# Send audio files to WhatsApp using AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

For some time I've been trying to implement the functionality of sending an audio file from my app through WhatsApp. When debugging everything seems to work correctly in the application, the audio file is generated and saved correctly in the external storage of the device, the WhatsApp window opens and allows me to select the chat to which I want to send the audio. The problem is that when I press the send button, WhatsApp returns the message "Failed to share. Please try again" (I leave a screenshot of the error so that it can be better viewed, in addition to the code used to implement the functionality).

- Capture of the error shown on the screen by WhatsApp when trying to share the audio:

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA5bU.jpg)
- Code used:

  ```
  //////Boton//////

  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

          try {
              String mediaPath = copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.audio1, "audio1.mp3");
              File myFile = new File(mediaPath);
              Uri newUri = getUriForFile(wspActivity.this, "com.restart.shareaudiofiles.fileprovider", myFile);
              Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              compartirAudio.setType("com.whatsapp");
              compartirAudio.setType("audio/mp3");
              compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,newUri);
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
  });

  /////funcion auxiliar/////
  private String copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String resourceName){
          String pathi= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/myProject/";
          boolean exists = (new File(pathi)).exists();
          if (!exists) {
              new File(pathi).mkdirs();
          }
          String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/TeLoResumoBotonera/" + resourceName;
          try{
              InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
              FileOutputStream out = null;
              out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
              byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
              int read = 0;
              try {
                  while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                      out.write(buff, 0, read);
                  }
              } finally {
                  in.close();
                  out.close();
              }
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return  pathSDCard;
      }

  /////Elementos agregados al manifest/////

      <queries>

          <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
          <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />

      </queries>


      <provider
              android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
              android:authorities="com.restart.shareaudiofiles.fileprovider"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">
              <meta-data
                  android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                  android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
      </provider>
  ```

I researched and implemented various resources to the manifest such as the fileprovider and queries with specific packages for WhatsApp (as can be seen in the code). However, the app still doesn't work. This makes me think that the problem could be in the mobile device that I am using to test the application (I would like to use another one to rule out this option, but I don't have an extra one). Another factor that I think may be causing problems is the version of Android (Android 11 in this case). This is because similar codes worked correctly in previous versions. If the device has nothing to do with it, then clearly there is a bug in my code. Due to this, in case someone manages to identify the improvement that could make the application work correctly, I would be very grateful if you can share it with me, or at least give me an idea of ​​where to address the problem.

Thank you very much for your time,

Regards!

Comment: can you send log of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see your error in the storage path. here is my code that useful to you.

If I am correct, the problem is that you declared the storage path incorrectly:

**The path you declared:** `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/myProject/"`

**updated path:** `context.getExternalFilesDir("MyProject")`

The `context.getExternalFilesDir("MyProject")` method will return the same path as you did.

1. first change your `copyFiletoExternalStorage` method like:

```java
private String copyFilesToStorage(Context context, int resourceId, String resourceName) {
        File destinationPath = context.getExternalFilesDir("MyProject");
        if (!destinationPath.exists()) {
            destinationPath.mkdirs();
        }
        String pathSDCard = new File(destinationPath, resourceName).getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return pathSDCard;
    }
```

2. change share Intent code to like:

```java
File file = new File(copyFilesToStorage(this, R.raw.audio1, "audio1.mp3"));
Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.restart.shareaudiofiles.fileprovider", file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType("audio/mp3");//Replace with audio/* to choose other extensions
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Audio"));
```

3. don't forgot about permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```